# Content Search Query Webpart

Tags: metadata, content-search-web-part, search-query

I have created a Content Search Query Web part which go through a document library and shows the result based on the column (metadata).

The old metadata was LGBTI and it was working fine, however since I have changed the LGBTI to LGBTIQA+ the search result is showing nothing.

So basically I have changed LGBTI to LGBTIQA+ and it stop working.

Below is my search query:

```
path:{Site.URL}/Documents  (IsDocument:"True" OR contentclass:"STS_ListItem") (PrgBusinessUnit={User.BusinessCategory} OR PrgBusinessUnit="All Business Units") ((PrgTopic="LGBTI") OR (PrgTopic="LGBTIQA+"))
```

[image]

Comment: Is PrgTopic a managed metadata column, a choice field or just text?

Comment: thanks for your reply, please see the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing: the display value of the 'LGBTI' term was changed to 'LGBTIQA+' and this messed up the query?
In that case you are lucky and the update pretty simple:
Update the query to use the guid of the term rather than the display value :
((PrgTopic="LGBTI") would look like ((PrgTopic:"the guid from the term "), pls note the change from = to :

I know that it makes query hard to read but it works and makes it resilient to changes

Comment: Hi Kasper, thanks for your message, i am not too sure what you mean when you say  use the guide of the term rather than display value, can you please provide me more information ?

Comment: This is my current query:                                                                                    
path:{Site.URL}/Documents  (IsDocument:"True" OR contentclass:"STS_ListItem") 
(PrgBusinessUnit={User.BusinessCategory} OR PrgBusinessUnit="All Business Units") 
((PrgTopic="LGBTI") OR (PrgTopic="LGBTIQA+"))

Comment: What does the mapping for PrgTopic look like?  A great tool when working with Sharepoint search is the SP Search Query tool on github as it show the field values for each managed property